# PHP 7.4.3 and modules 'dom' and 'simplexml'

Tags: php, dom, xampp, simplexml

I installed PHP 7.4.3 on my xampp server and everything works fine except these two issues:

I checked php.ini file but there is no these two files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include the error messages. You can [edit] to add them now, but you should also include exactly what you've tried so far - searching for the error message may give you tips.